# Existence of the basis which makes the determinant function $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant

In the [book](http://hive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of Linear Algebra by Werner Greub, at page 103, it is given in the Proposition that

> Let E be an n-dimensional vector space and fix a non- zero determinant
>   function $\Delta$ in E. Then every skew symmetric n-linear map $\phi$
>   from E to a vector space F determines a unique vector $b \in F$ such
>   that $$\phi (x_1, ..., x_n) = \Delta (x_1, ..., x_n) \cdot b$$

And in the proof it says that

> Choose a basis $a_1, ..., a_n$ of E so that $\Delta (a_1, ..., a_n) =$
>   $1$

But how can we be sure that there such an basis in E ?

I mean in the previous page, to prove the existence of a non-zero determinant function in E, it defines $\Delta$ as

$$\Delta = \sum_\sigma \epsilon_\sigma (\sigma \phi)$$, where $\phi$ is a linear function in E, but in the above, $\Delta$ is any non-zero determinant function in E, not the one as defined with that sum.

Comment: What's the connection between the $a_k$'s and the $x_k$'s?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $x_k = \sum_v \lambda_v a_v$ for some $\lambda_v$ since $\{ a_v\}$ forms a basis for $E$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm sorry,  there was a mistake, in the proof it should be $\Delta (a_1, ..., a_n) = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Delta (a_1, ..., a_n)=\lambda\neq0$, consider the basis $\bigl(\frac1\lambda a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\bigr)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ with $\Delta(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\ne0$.
They have to be linearly dependent: from the alternating property,
if one $x_i$ is a linear combination of the others, $\Delta(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ will be zero. Now multiply $x_1$ by a scalar to make the answer $1$.

Comment: How can you be sure that there exists such a scalar ?

Comment: Plus, see my edit, I have written wrong something in the proof part.

Comment: @Leth Then substitute $a_i$ for $x_i$ in my proof.

Comment: Ok, but again, the question still remains. How can we sure that there exits such a scalar ?